# Xamarin Forms - Multiple Polygons on Map using Custom Map Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/) Xamarin forms tutorial on highlighting a region on a map using a Custom Map Renderer. This tutorial shows you how to add one polygon to the a map in Xamarin Forms, but doesn't explain how to extend the code to allow multiple polygons on a map.

How do I tweak this implementation to allow multiple polygons on a map for iOS? Here is my iOS code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MapOverlay.iOS
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        MKPolygonRenderer polygonRenderer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                if (nativeMap != null) {
                    nativeMap.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
                    nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = null;
                    polygonRenderer = null;
                }
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;

                nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;

                CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[formsMap.ShapeCoordinates.Count];

                int index = 0;
                foreach (var position in formsMap.ShapeCoordinates)
                {
                    coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                    index++;
                }

                var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
                nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);
            }
        }




 MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
      {
          if (polygonRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null)) {
              var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
              polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon) {
                  FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                  StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                  Alpha = 0.4f,
                  LineWidth = 9
              };
          }
          return polygonRenderer;
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The first problem is in your `if (e.NewElement != null){...}` code. If you want to have multiple polygons, `formsMap.ShapeCoordinates` should be of a `List<List<Position>>` type. So it can have multiple polygons' coordinate groups. As you code shows, it uses `List<Position>`. And your code triggers `nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);` only once which adds only one overlay into your map.
2. Change the `if (polygonRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null))` in `GetOverlayRenderer` to `if (!Equals(overlayWrapper, null))`. Otherwise, every time the map adds a overlay and triggers the method, it will return the first `polygonRenderer`.

Here's my code for example:

1. Code in **MainPage.xaml** in PCL:

   ```
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}" HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />
   </ContentPage.Content>
   ```
2. I added two polygons' position lists in **MainPage.xaml.cs** in PCL:

   ```
   List<Position> pos = new List<Position> { new Position(39.939889, 116.423493), new Position(39.930622, 116.423924), new Position(39.930733,116.441135), new Position(39.939944, 116.44056) };
   List<Position> posi = new List<Position> { new Position(39.934633, 116.399921), new Position(39.929709, 116.400208), new Position(39.929792, 116.405994), new Position(39.934689,116.405526) };
   customMap.ShapeCoordinates.Add(pos);
   customMap.ShapeCoordinates.Add(posi);
   customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(39.934689, 116.405526), Distance.FromMiles(1.5)));
   ```
3. Code in **CustomMap.cs** in PCL:

   ```
   public class CustomMap : Map
   {
       public List<List<Position>> ShapeCoordinates { get; set; }

       public CustomMap()
       {
           ShapeCoordinates = new List<List<Position>>();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Code in **CustomMapRenderer.cs** in iOS platform:

   ```
   class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
   {
       MKPolygonRenderer polygonRenderer;

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

           if (e.OldElement != null)
           {
               var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
               if (nativeMap != null)
               {
                   nativeMap.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
                   nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = null;
                   polygonRenderer = null;
               }
           }

           if (e.NewElement != null)
           {
               var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
               var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
               nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;

               foreach (List<Position> positionList in formsMap.ShapeCoordinates)
               {

                   CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[positionList.Count];

                   int index = 0;
                   foreach (var position in positionList)
                   {
                       coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                       Console.WriteLine(position.Latitude +" : "+ position.Longitude);

                       index++;
                   }



                   var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
                   nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);

               }
           }
       }



       MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
       {
           if (!Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
           {         
               var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
               polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon)
               {
                   FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                   StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                   Alpha = 0.4f,
                   LineWidth = 9

               };
           }
           return polygonRenderer;
       }
   }
   ```

**It works like this:**

[image]

Comment: Wow Kevin, thanks for the comprehensive answer I will read through it now

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer to this extended map control when writing my own custom renderer.

[TKCustomMap Github Repo](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap)

Looking at the iOS renderer for polygons they simply loop through the polygons on the Forms Map and add another overlay to the iOS Map i.e.

```
       foreach (var position in formsMap.ShapeCoordinates)
        {
            coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
            nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately Steve I think this is not correct as I think you can only have 1 Overlay per Overlay Renderer, is that right?

Comment: I believe you can have as many overlays on the map as you like and assign the overlay renderer to each one . It goes Map > Overlays > Renderer

Comment: I updated my answer with code to show adding the overlays in a loop.